# How to know the number of iterations in a loop

Tags: loops, iterator

```
static void bar(int n) {
   for (int i = n!; i>=1; i=i/2);
  }
```

How many times will this loop run for n? I assume it will include a log because we're dividing by 2 each time. I think it will be log n, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: What is `lg(n!)`? As pointed out this (`lg`) is due to the i/2 change each time.

Comment: does this code even run?

Comment: @Nabin Not as presented. There is no postfix unary `!` operator in Java.

Comment: No I'm just trying to figure how many times it would actually run code

Comment: It should be `O(log(n!)) = O(n log(n))`

Comment: @prisonbreakx Consider the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you just want to check how many times it runs, you can do the following **(Of course your code won't run)**:

```
int counter = 0;
    static void bar(int n) {
       for (int i = n!; i>=1; i=i/2){
counter++;
}
      }
```

And finally print counter as

```
System.out.println(counter);//this will display how many iterations were achieved
```

**P.S.** You need to do something other than **n!**
May be like

```
static void bar(int n) {
   for (int i = factorialOf(n); i>=1; i=i/2);
  }
```

And create a function like this:

```
public int factorialOf(int n){//assuming your return isn't huge else use long or double
//your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So with the helper function, the big O would be n*log(n!) right?

Comment: O(log(n!)) = O(n log(n))